# Matlab: Some Issues with HeatMap

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

Please find below a copy of the HeatMap that I generated with Matlab. I have two
problems that I would like to address:

1) As you can see, the HeatMap has just three different values that it displays.

```
Red   = 500
Green = 0
Black = 250
```

Unfortuantely, the Colorbar displays around 10 different values, even for colors that
are not used in the HeatMap. I see no option how I could change that. Does anyone know
how I could customise this Colorbar/label so that it just covers the three values actually used?

2) When I try to plot this HeatMap I get the following error message:

```
hmo = HeatMap(data)
HeatMap object with 20 rows and 20 columns.
plot(hmo);
Error using ==> figure
Invalid property found.
Object Name :  figure
Property Name :  'PagePosition'.
Error in ==> HeatMap.plot at 42
hFig = figure('Renderer',     'ZBuffer',...
```

Many thanks for your help!
Patrick

[image: Matlab HeatMap]

Comment: Where is the code for the `HeatMap`?  This issue appears to be in there. Also, it's `PaperPosition` in matlab for positioning the figure not `PagePosition`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/heatmap.html), you can tell `HeatMap` to use a custom colormap:

```
HeatMap(Data, ...'Colormap', ColormapValue, ...)
```

You want just 3 values, so make the colormap with 3 rows:

```
cmap = [0 1 0; %# green
        0 0 0; %# black
        1 0 0;]%# red
```

Then, when you call `HeatMap`, include the name-value pair;

```
hmo = HeatMap(data,'colormap',cmap);
```

Note: You may need to set the `clim` axes property to `[0 500]` manually.

Answer (score 0):

The `HeatMap` function doesn't look to be a built-in function, so it makes it difficult to say what is going on in there. However your colorbar issue is easier to solve.

The problem is that your colormap is not only composed of those three colors.
This example below, should suffice to show you how to change that manually, if you need to.

```
% Create some sample data and plot it
p = peaks;
surf(p)
colorbar
```

This will display the figure:

[image: Figure using default colormap]

Now, if you want to make your customised `colormap` to display only green, black and red (in this bottom to top order):

```
yourColorMap = [0 1 0; 0 0 0; 1 0 0]; % green, black red RGB code. One per row
colormap(yourColorMap)
```

Will make your image look like this:

[image: Figure with your customised colormap]